# How to add SSL Option laravel SMTP Mail

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

I am using laravel smtp mail. but i dont know where i want to add ssl option like below code

```
'ssloptions' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => env('MAIL_SSLOPTIONS_ALLOW_SELF_SIGNED', false),
        'verify_peer' => env('MAIL_SSLOPTIONS_VERIFY_PEER', true),
        'verify_peer_name' => env('MAIL_SSLOPTIONS_VERIFY_PEER_NAME', true),
    ],
```

It works in PhpMailler class

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This  works for me at Laravel 5.3. Don't forget to add verify_peer_name, it`s not mentioned in article, but it is in the comments.
https://squarecone.com/2016/05/email-via-smtp-self-signed-certificate-laravel-5-2/